# websetup in .net

Tags: .net, web-deployment-project

I created a websetup project in .net. When I use the installer, by default the installer installs the web application in c:\inetpub\wwwroot. But I like to configure the location during the installation. How can I do that?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that using the standard Visual Studio built Web Installer. I'd recommend taking a look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), as that gives you a *lot* of control, or failing that something like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Answer (score -2):

Have yo tried to set the "AllowDirectoryBrowsing" property of your web application folder to "True" ?

I hope it helps...

Comment: AllowDirectoryBrowsing won't solve this problem, it'll just make the virtual directory contents listable via a web browser!